# Bundling, but per user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

We have javascript files which get bundled and compressed using the normal asp.net mvc mechanism.

We also have some javascript files which get transformed via httphandlers to deal with phrases, colour schemes, etc. At present these are simply linked in, could these be compressed and bundled but at the user level?

Unfortunately we can't group these easily, but even if we could we couldn't do it within a global.ascx file without a lot of rejigging. I mention this as it's not simply a case of having bundle1 = french, bundle2=german, etc

Compression I'm assuming could be done via IIS and static compression, but bundling?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.

The easiest I can see is to skip the whole Bundling and Minification that is shipped with MVC 5.

Handle it yourself. Generate CSS for your user and have it go through this piece of code:

```
public static string RemoveWhiteSpaceFromStylesheets(string body)
{
  body = Regex.Replace(body, @"[a-zA-Z]+#", "#");
  body = Regex.Replace(body, @"[\n\r]+\s*", string.Empty);
  body = Regex.Replace(body, @"\s+", " ");
  body = Regex.Replace(body, @"\s?([:,;{}])\s?", "$1");
  body = body.Replace(";}", "}");
  body = Regex.Replace(body, @"([\s:]0)(px|pt|%|em)", "$1");

  // Remove comments from CSS
  body = Regex.Replace(body, @"/\*[\d\D]*?\*/", string.Empty);

  return body;
}
```

Or any CSS minifier for that matter. Just make sure to include proper caching tag for your user and you won't even have to regenerate it too much.

---

[Code taken from Mads Kristensen](http://madskristensen.net/post/efficient-stylesheet-minification-in-c)